# "network webgateway declared as external, but could not be found" on WSL2 when doing docker-compose up

Tags: docker, wsl2

```
docker-compose up
network webgateway declared as external, but could not be found
```

I am getting this when I am doing docker-compose up on WSL2 and I did:

```
docker network create gateway
```

I did this on another WSL2 instance and it worked perfectly so I am wondering why it isn't working on another WSL2 instance. I know it should be working, because I did it on another WSL2 instance, but I am wondering if there's some kind of network config I did on the other one I didn't do on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I had to reinstall Docker Desktop, because I installed Docker Desktop before installing WSL2, because I used docker for some personal project. So just uninstall and reinstall if you get the same error.